# Generating ARIMA(p,1,q) from ARMA(p,q)

Tags: r, time-series, self-study, arima

We know that ARIMA(p,1,q) can be generated as ct=yt-y(t-1) where ct is ARMA and yt is ARIMA while yt-1 is lag of ARIMA?I want to generate ARIMA from above equation which will be equal to yt=ct/(1-B) where B is lag operator.

How to generate ARIMA in R from above equation?

Your input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is already answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201531/given-armap-q-can-a-arimap-1-q-model-be-created?rq=1).

To summarize, depending on how many times your series has to be differentiated to become stationary (in your case that should be 1), you can generate your ARIMA with:

```
library(forecast)
model <- Arima(timeseries,order=c(p-1,1,q))
```

to doublecheck you can compare

```
model_ARMA <- Arima(timeseries,order=c(p,0,q))
model_ARIMA <- Arima(timeseries,order=c(p-1,1,q))
```

both should yield same results. 
Maybe as a more generalized form:

```
model_ARMA <- Arima(timeseries,order=c(p,0,q))
model_ARIMA <- Arima(timeseries,order=c(p-n,n,q))
```

I hope I understood your question correctly. 
best regards

Comment: I wanted to know Using parameter μ,φ1,φ2,θ1, and θ2 . Generate three time series for the ARIMA(2,2,2) for each of the following values of σa: 0.8, 0.1, and 0.01.

I attempted the question like this:

#Check whether AR root are stationary rootsar=polyroot(c(1,0.15,-0.20))

Mod(rootar)

#Check whether MA root are invertibe

rootsma=polyroot(c(1,0.05,-0.25))

Mod(rootsma)

#Generating ARMA for different value of sigma(assuming n=1008)

arma=arima.sim(n=1004,list(ar=c(0.15,-0.20),ma=c(0.05,-0.25)),mean=1,s=0.8) Using above equation could how  I generate ARIMA(2,2,2)?